# Meaning of "conjured out" in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Here is the paragraph that contains the words:

> As Karl Marx and Friedrich Engels saw clearly, the 19th-century
>   business class
>
> > created more massive and more colossal productive
> >     forces than all preceding generations together. Subjection of Nature’s
> >     forces to man, machinery, application of chemistry to industry and
> >     agriculture, steam-navigation, railways, electric telegraphs, clearing
> >     of whole continents for cultivation, canalisation of rivers, whole
> >     populations conjured out of the ground—what earlier century had even a
> >     presentiment that such productive forces slumbered in the lap of
> >     social labor?

What does "conjured out" mean in this context? What is it that the whole populations conjured out of the ground?

Answer (score 2):

This is a metaphorical use of the word "to conjure", which means to summon by magic.

The author, to me, is expressing that the explosive growth of technology and population happened so quickly, and started with so little, that it is almost magical.

This could be reasonably restated as:

> whole populations came seemingly out of nowhere

Comment: Isn't the verb "conjure" a transitive verb? doesn't it require an object?

Comment: I think your *came seemingly out of nowhere* sounds much more natural for OP's context. Alternatively, if sticking with ***conjured***, it's worth noting that [*conjured out of **thin air***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22conjured+out+of+thin+air%22) is significantly more common (it's only a metaphoric reference, so it might as well be the one people *usually* use).

Comment: @ammarx: The "object" is ***whole populations***. There's no "subject" because it's a "passive" form. God (or similar) conjured those populations up, apparently.

Comment: ...also note that a goodly proportion of the "standard" idiom usages occur as [*conjured **up** out of thin {air}*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conjured+out+of+thin%2Cconjured+up+out+of+thin&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconjured%20out%20of%20thin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconjured%20up%20out%20of%20thin%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Shouldn't it be "whole populations were conjured out of the ground"?

Comment: The paragraph has broken parallel structure already, to me it reads as a deliberate choice by the author but it's definitely not perfectly grammatical as written.